# How do I get multiple process id of background processes in bash

Tags: bash, shell, gawk

How do I get the process id for a given bash cmd

```
vmstat 3 | gawk '{ now=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T "); print now $0}' >> foo.txt & p_id=$!
```

`echo $p_id` outputs the gawk process id. But I also want the process id of vmstat.

How do I get the process id of vmstat

can some one tell me how do I get the process id of vmstat.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an explicit named pipe, rather than a pipeline.

```
mkfifo pipe
vmstat 3 > pipe & vmstat_pid=$!
gawk '...' < pipe >> foo.txt & gawk_pid=$!
wait $vmstat_pid $gawk_pid
rm pipe
```

Comment: I have resolved. Pleae find below the code I used.
while :
do
    vmstat | tail -1 | gawk '{ now=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T "); print $0 " " now }' >> foo.txt;
    sleep 3;
done

Answer (score 0):

```
$(jobs -p vmstat)
```

Here, the *jobspec* is `vmstat`:

> There are a number of ways to refer to a job in the shell. The character `%` introduces a job name. Job number n may be referred to as `%n`. A job may also be referred to using a prefix of the name used to start it, or using a substring that appears in its command line.

Find out more about the `jobs` keyword in the [Jobs Control section of the Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control).